# How to restrict Docker login and pull from private registry in Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

I have several docker registries working with Artifactory.  I can login successfully, and push/pull images.  I'm noticing it lets me login to a registry with any Artifactory id, even if not listed under permissions for that Docker registry in Artifactory.  It does restrict where a user can push as expected and will fail on a 'client doesn't have permission' error.  However, it also doesn't seem to restrict pulling artifacts as I was able to pull from a registry the user doesn't have access to, but same id failed correctly on a push.

I couldn't find anything useful on a Google search.  Anyone know what I'm missing to restrict only users with correct permissions to login to the registry and also push/pull?

Comment: Your post is missing a lot of important information:
1. Which artifactory version are you using. 
2. Under the repository in the tree browser, go to the 'effective permissions' tab and verify that the user you say that don't have permissions to that repository is actually not listed there. 
3. After you run the pull/push with the user that don't have permissions, what do you see in the request.log and access.log?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information:   1) I'm on v5.8.3.  2)  I verified my test_user id has no permissions to the repository and is not listed.  3)  The logs were helpful.  When I run `docker login` from the client with the id that doesn't have access I get a **login succeeded** msg.  When I look in the log right after it says **2018-02-22 14:34:11,869 [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/127.0.0.1.**  So it looks like the server is denying it, but client msg is misleading.  For the pull I verified the image wasn't on the client and tried to pull again.

Comment: continued....I get the msg **"Unsupported docker v1 repository request for 'docker-local'**.  When I look in the log it shows 2 lines stating **20180222142813|30|REQUEST|192.168.100.11|test_user|GET|/api/docker/docker-local/v1/repositories/alpine/images|HTTP/1.0|400|0
20180222142848|0|REQUEST|192.168.100.11|non_authenticated_user|GET|/api/docker/docker-local/v2/|HTTP/1.0|401|0**.  So it looks like it's rejecting correctly, just curious why on the client side it doesn't show the 401 or login rejected msgs.  I think the pull wasn't failing before because the image already was on the client.

Comment: It could be that the reason was caching on the client side... Glad to hear that this is not a real issue :)